# How to use a color from angular material palette?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material and want to use colors from the palette for my styles. I found answers using `mat-color()` but it seems that doesn't work anymore.

My styles.scss looks like:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$web-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$web-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$web-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$web-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $web-primary,
    accent: $web-accent,
    warn: $web-warn,
  )
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($web-theme);
```

I want to add something like `a {color: $web-primary}`

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the docs:

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#note-using-the-code-mat-color-code-function-to-extract-colors-from-a-palette

You can access the color in this way:

```
$color-config: mat.get-color-config($web-theme);
$primary-palette: map.get($color-config, 'primary');

a {
  color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 500);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```